# Does getting out of the AWS Simple Mail Service sandbox require a support plan (other than basic)?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'm trying to get a Simple Email Service account running.

I'm curious if I need a support plan (let's say developer - at 49$ per month currently) in order to make my account production-ready.

These are the support plans: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/compare-plans/

Currently, the sandbox only allows sending mails from and to verified addresses, and the limits on the account are quite low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no support plan is needed to get out of the sandbox - two entirely different issues.

Having or not having a support plan has nothing to do with your sending limits.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Increase Limit request without having a support plan. You should have the option to create a case in the support center and choose **Service Limit Increase**. Then, just explain the reason for the request that it should be available in a short time.

What you can't do without a support plan is create a case for **Technical Support**.